# EqualsIgnoreCase function - Exception : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException

Tags: apache-pig, equals, ignore-case

EqualsIgnoreCase function - Exception : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException

**Input :**

```
 a.csv
 -------
  a
  A
 (blank/empty line)
  b
  B
  c
  C
```

Objective : To select the records which are 'a', 'A', 'b' and 'B'.

**Approach 1 :**

```
    A = LOAD 'a.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (value:chararray);
    B = FILTER A BY LOWER(value) IN ('a','b');
    DUMP B;

    Output :
     (a)
     (A)
     (b)
     (B)
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
    C = FILTER A BY EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'a') or  EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'b');

    Output :
     2015-04-27 23:48:21,958 [Thread-30] WARN   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0014
        org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.EqualsIgnoreCase.exec(EqualsIgnoreCase.java:50)
```

Trying to understand why this exception is getting thrown. I understand that its because of the blank record.

Tried checking for value NOT being null or empty, still the same error.

```
  D = FILTER A BY (value IS NOT NULL) OR (TRIM(value) != '') AND (EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'a') or  EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'b'));
```

Any inputs/ thoughts on achieving our objective using **Approach 2** is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, string functions `EqualsIgnoreCase` and `TRIM` are not able to handle blank string in the input.
To solve this issue,what ever you did in the last stmt is right, just remove the  `Trim` function it will work.

```
C = FILTER A BY (value is not null) and (EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'a') or  EqualsIgnoreCase(value, 'b'));
```

Is `not null condition` will take care of empty(null, space and tab) chars, so `TRIM` function is not required.